# Integrate sharepoint with a NoSQL database?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, database

I was wondering if it is possible to connect/integrate sharepoint with a NoSQL database (e.g mongodb, couchdb, etc)?

I wasn't able to find any information on how this can be done. I did find something about "Business Connectivity Source" - would this be it? I think I also read somewhere that connection to a NoSQL data source is not available by default.

I would like to dynamically create a list, view etc by getting data from a NoSQL data source.